# Does c# have a VB.NET-equivalent for shorthand array declaration like {"string1","string2"}?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, types, type-inference

In VB.NET, you can instantiate and immediately use an array like this:

`Dim b as Boolean = {"string1", "string2"}.Contains("string1")`

In c#, however, it appears you have to do this:

`bool b = new string[] { "string1", "string2" }.Contains("string1");`

Does c# have equivalent shorthand syntax that uses type inference to determine the type of array without it having to be explicitly declared?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Implicitly typed arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx) do not have to include their type, provided it can be [inferred](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx):

```
bool b = new [] { "string1", "string2" }.Contains("string1");
```

Comment: And you can read more about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx

Comment: Ah that's too bad.  I was hoping not to even have to specify even `new []`, but I guess it is what it is.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It called [`Implicitly Typed Arrays`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx)

> You can create an implicitly-typed array in which the type of the
>   array instance is inferred from the elements specified in the array
>   initializer. The rules for any implicitly-typed variable also apply to
>   implicitly-typed arrays.

```
static void Main()
    {
        var a = new[] { 1, 10, 100, 1000 }; // int[] 
        var b = new[] { "hello", null, "world" }; // string[] 
    }
```

You can use it also for *jagged array.*